# how to secure zip file upload?

Tags: java, security, zip, uploading

I've a project in netbeans which my employer wants me to add a bulk file upload.
The requirement was ,the user will put a csv file and some images in a folder in client side. on the file upload page he will choose the csv file and i have to upload the images in the folder along with the csv.
After a short research i found that the client side file location and details can't be accessed from the server side so instead of uploading a single file and  the contents in the folder which it belong, the user will zip all the files and upload the zip file .
Now i'm conserned about the security risks of uploading a zip file.

1. What all are the measures should i take to prevent the upload of malecious scripts and files along with the zip?
2. Is it possible to validate the file content before it reach the server ?
3. Is it possible to validate it securely even after it reached the server side ?

Comment: If you're particularly worried about zip files (although it's not entirely clear why), just don't have the user upload zip files. Upload forms can take multiple files.

Comment: What are you concerned about? A zip file is just a file, like any other file. A sequence of bytes. There's nothing dangerous about uploading a zip file. What could be a problem is if you opened the zip file, and executed executable files stored inside the zip file. But why would you do that?

Comment: I'm worried about zip files because after uploading it i have to unzip it to a folder in the server and have to do some operations.What if the zip contain executable files which can be executed after reaching the server. About upload forms, I've never used it before .What i am trying to upload here will contain around 3000 jpg files and a csv file which contain some details and the name of a particular image.

Comment: Executable files don't just execute by themselves. If you don't execute them, they won't be executed. But you can just remove all non .jpg  files, and remove all the files that have an executable flag (if any, I'm not even sure that is possible with zip files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- scan the zip files once they arrive at the server.

2.- unlikely. even if you use Javascript as front-end, it doesn't have access to the users file system.

3.- yes, for example with "clamav", but notice that no antivirus is 100% effective.

the steps are:

- install clamav
- configure clamav to update periodically its virus database
- schedule a cron job that continuously scans all files that are in certain directory (the directory where you upload the users files)
- delete files that contain viruses

for example:

# dnf install -y clamav

# dnf install -y clamav-update

$ clamscan java_error_in_IDEA_6451.log.zip

LibClamAV Warning: **************************************************

LibClamAV Warning: ***  The virus database is older than 7 days!**

LibClamAV Warning:    **Please update it as soon as possible.    ***

LibClamAV Warning: **************************************************

java_error_in_IDEA_6451.log.zip: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------

Known viruses: 4490129

Engine version: 0.99.2

Scanned directories: 0

Scanned files: 1

Infected files: 0

Data scanned: 0.37 MB

Data read: 0.03 MB (ratio 13.43:1)

Time: 6.239 sec (0 m 6 s)

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus is optional. Everything you need here is to validate and safely extract files from archive to your server storage. I don't recommend to use system utilities for this (`zip`, etc.). It's better to take some library for working with zip archives and write code for its processing.

Here's possible algorithm for validating files in archive. You should iterate through every file and check if:

1. File size is too big.
2. Filename is too long.
3. Directory structure is too big.
4. Filename includes `../`.
5. File extension is not in white list.
6. File has attributes of [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).
7. Other rules.

If something is true for your current file, then it's better to stop processing of such archive and show error for client.

When you've checked everything, then you can start to extract files. From this moment you can try to validate content of file using [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) or [exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) tools.

Also, you can require archives with some special structure. For example, all images must be in `images` folder, archive must have only 1 level of folders and so on.